# average distance between a point and points on a circle

Tags: probability, geometry, polar-coordinates

> What is the average of $\frac{1}{d^a}$ where $a>0$ and $d$ is the distance between point at $(x,y)=(-l,0)$ and points on a circle with radius $r$ centered at point $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

I am totally confused how to solve this.

Comment: what is $\ell$?

Comment: @AlainChau $\ell$ is a constant representing the location of the first point on the left side of the $x$ axis.